# NO java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a project in eclipse which was working fine untile a few minutes ago. I added a JDBC driver ad tried to run it, now even previous runnable file are giving me

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sample**

Does anyone have any idea why it is happening does it have anything to do with the jar?
I have even removed the jar.

Comment: How did you add the JAR file? Include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Please refer to the possible reasons for this error in the below mentioned post :

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Hadoop Basics' MapReduce Program

Comment: This error is almost always due to a missing or mismatched JAR file.  Note that very often the named class *can* be found in the classpath, but some other class needed to verify the named class is either missing or the wrong version.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, one by one

1. If you are using libraries, check whether everything is included to the project properly.
2. Rebuild the project
3. 'worked few minutes ago' means it used to work. Did you add any new code? Then the error is there, check whether those codes call other classes, and whether they are available
4. Restart IDE

Once I used the following to solve the same issue

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html

If all above failed, that may be due to crash in JVM. I have experienced that as well.